# Remove 'Google Actions' project from Google home app

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I have a Raspberry Pi running Home Assistant (Hassio actually) and it is communicating with Google to make the lights go on and off using Google Assistant. To do that I have followed the cook book on the home assistant website. When Hassio updated from an API password to Oauth, I created a new project, because I had some issues with discovering devices.

In the current situation, when I ask Google to turn on the lights, it turns on the light, but also states that [lastprojectname] is not reachable. I did remove the project from the Google Actions console, but it does still show up in the Google Home app. I unlinked the account there, but still the same issue. So the old project is still in the linkable account list.

When I ask Google to turn on the lights in the 'office' (for example), it states, 'OK turning off 4 lights' while there are only 2. The lights are not in the app anymore, the account is not linked. Very weird. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me some of the time (I'm also using Home Assistant, but just starting with Google Assistant integration). When it happens, I just link, and then re-unlink the app. It usually sticks the second time.

I know that's the equivalent of "turn it off, then turn it back on", but it works, and I don't have a better solution :|