# Remove Actions on Google project from Google Home app Home control page

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-assistant

Some time ago, I made a few test projects on Actions on Google. I later removed these projects by deleting them on Actions on Google and/or on GCP. However, these projects still appear in the Google Home app:

[image: Screenshot from the Google Home app]

I've tried relinking them (as per [Remove 'Google Actions' project from Google home app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53813983/remove-google-actions-project-from-google-home-app)), but this doesn't seem to make a difference. The endpoints for the project probably aren't live anymore, so the relinking process fails without error.

How can I go about removing these projects from the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently a bug - I would recommend subscribing to [the public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148664341) related to this to be informed of updates once it is solved.